# An inequality of eigenvalues of $A$ and $U^TAU$, where $A$ is symmetric, $U^TU = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

The question is as follows:

> $A$ is a $J\times J$ symmetric matrix, $U$ is a $J\times K$ matrix where $K\le J$. Suppose that $U^TU=I_K$. Please show that $\lambda_{j}(U^TAU)\le\lambda_{j}(A)$

I have tried to do eigenvalue decomposition for $A$ and then $U^TAU$ can be described as $P\Lambda P^T$ where $PP^T=I$. However I can't find any fine property. Any hint or solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to find eigenvalues of symmetric matrix? Did you try $j=1$?

Comment: Are the eigenvalues $\lambda_1(A),\dots,\lambda_j(A)$ taken in increasing order or in decreasing order?

Comment: You should find that the [Courant-Fischer min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) is useful

Comment: Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing shows this and more....